# Hql clause is null in clause case , not working as in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hql

I made one query in mysql.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t2.ammout * CASE WHEN t2.idAccountDeb = :accountSelec AND  
(t2.idAccountDeb <> t2.idAccountCred OR t2.idAccountCred IS NULL) 
THEN 1 WHEN t2.idAccountCred = :accountSelec AND
(t2.idAccountDeb <> t2.idAccountCred OR t2.idAccountDeb IS NULL) THEN
-1 ELSE 0 END),0) FROM TransactionAccount t2 WHERE 
(t2.idAccountDeb = :accountSelec OR t2.idAccountCred = :accountSelec) AND
t2.dtInf <= :dateSelec
```

I tried to convert in Hql

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t2.ammout * CASE WHEN t2.accountDeb = :accountSelec AND 
(t2.accountDeb <> t2.accountCred OR t2.accountCred IS NULL) THEN 1
WHEN t2.accountCred = :accountSelec AND (t2.accountDeb <> t2.accountCred OR
t2.accountDeb IS NULL) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END),0) FROM TransactionAccount t2 
WHERE   (t2.accountDeb = :accountSelec OR t2.accountCred = :accountSelec) 
AND t2.dtInf <= :dateSelec
```

But in hql is returning 0.00, this `END),0)` . In mysql, 150.97.

This occurs, when account debit or account credit is null.

What am I doing wrong?
Example:
If transaction contain one account credit or account debit with value null,the query can not capture in the clause "is null".

My beans:

```
    @Entity
    public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(length = 40)
    private String cod;
    private boolean credit;
    private String name;//CTA
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCompany")
    private Company company;


    @Version
    private int version;

    //getter and setters
}

    @Entity
    public class Transaction implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String history;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAccountDeb")
    @OneToOne
    private Account accountDeb;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idAccountCred")
    @OneToOne
    private Account accountCred;
    private BigDecimal ammount;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dtInf;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dtPosted;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dtModif;  
    private TypeTransaction type;
    @Version
    private int version;
}
```

Comment: i am not sure, but i don't think that (for example) **THEN -1 ELSE 0 END** is valid **HQL** (but of course, i may be wrong...)

Comment: If transaction contain one account credit or account debit with value null,the query can not capture in the clause "is null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution.

Just put id in comparation accounts

New Query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t2.ammount * CASE WHEN t2.accountDeb.id = :accountSelec 
           AND (t2.accountDeb.id <> t2.accountCred.id OR t2.accountCred.id is null) THEN 1
           WHEN  (t2.accountDeb.id <> t2.accountCred.id 
           OR t2.accountDeb.id is null) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END),0)
           FROM TransactionAccount t2 WHERE (t2.accountDeb = :accountSelec 
           OR t2.accountCred = :accountSelec) AND t2.dtInf <= :dateSelec
```